# How to return a value from a prototype method

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

## What I have

I want to return the id of the database if someone give me the session login id.

```
SqlLite.prototype.GetClientDatabaseId = function GetClientDatabaseId(id) {
   this.database.get('select id from Clients where LoginId=$id',
   { $id: id },
   (err, row) => {
       if(err === null) {
           return row.id;
       } else {
           log.LogLine(1, "SqlLite GetClientDatabaseId: Could not get client database id from loginid "+id);
           log.LogLine(1, "Message: "+err);
           return false;
       };
   });
};
```

If I log via console.log the result of the database is successfull and the row.id also exist.

## Problem

If I call this method I get return just undefined. Is it not possible to return something from a prototype method? Did I always need a callback?

Comment: Did you mean the prototype is asynchron or the database method?

Comment: The database method is asynchronous, that's why it has the callback function.

Comment: Oh... yes you´re right... But in the ajax request I´ve the option async: false. But how I can make it in the database method?

Comment: Umh ... Even if the code in your example was synchronous, the return value from `SqlLite.GetClientDatabaseId` would still be `undefined`, since the method doesn't return anything. It's the `get` method of `this.database` object, which calls the callback, that's the place where the return value of the callback function is returned to. In this case it will go directly to the bit space. You better just to learn to use async programming "schemas", especially when you're on node.js.

Comment: How would it be correct?

Comment: Please read some answers in the linked dup, there are some really good explanations how to handle asynchronous coding.

Comment: Looks like I should use callbacks again